# Make Groupbox's controls readonly when is radiobutton clicked in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have many textbox inside a group box so when radio button is clicked i want to make these controls readonly. Is it possible,and again on another radio button click again i want to make readonly false in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick event for your radio button add code that sets your groupbox.IsEnabled to false.  That should make the control readonly.